# Active Directory logout button for Web based application

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a program that authenticates users using Active Directory. I am looking for a simple way to log off users.

Comment: What provider do you use to store the logged on users? Depending on that, simply remove the user from this storage. Eg. removing his session will log the user off. Feel free to share some code/used frameworks to help us beeing able to help you. :)

Comment: The logged on users are not stored anywhere.Users are Logged in Via Active Directory Authentication

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In ASP.NET you can log an user off, using this method (C#):

```
AuthenticationManager.SignOut(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
```

When using Owin you would do so:

```
Context.GetOwinContext().Authentication.SignOut(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
```